# Docker + NGINX + SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker

I have a trivial NGINX proxy config (below) that uses my new SSL cert (first time I'm trying this).

I've deployed this via Docker extending the standard "nginx" image. I'm reasonably sure my InstantSSL cert file is valid, but the server isn't returning a valid SSL connection.

I'm getting the following error:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect MY_DOMAIN.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
22489:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake
```

I've tried other tools too:

```
$ ./cipherscan -v https://MY_DOMAIN.com
handshake failed, no ciphersuite was returned
```

And finally, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html returns "No secure protocols supported"

I've tried various combinations of **ssl_protocols** and **ssl_ciphers** settings, but the nginx docs say the defaults should be fine.

NGINX works fine on port 80 (i.e., with my standard virtual host setting listening on 80), so general server set-up seems OK.

Anyone have anything else I can try?

```
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name MY_DOMAIN.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/MY_DOMAIN.key;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://frontend;

      proxy_redirect http:// https://;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

User Error:

I had 443 exposed in my Dockerfile, but not in my Docker Cloud stackfile (so the hosted containers port was blocked).

I figured this out by testing nginx locally (adding an /etc/hosts entry to "fake" my prod server) and it worked correctly (outside of docker).